# How do I change alternator pulley on 2001 Fiat Ducato?

Tags: alternator, belt, fiat, pulley

[image]

I need to change the belt (closest one in picture) as it's become very loose. There doesn't seem to be a tensioner pulley, so do I just remove the bolt in the center pulley in order to remove the belts? Or is the far pulley in the picture a tensioner?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to the site. By the looks of it, you've got a pretty hefty oil leak going on there. It appears to be coming from further up the engine, so I'd suggest looking at the valve cover.

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the large bolt holding the alternator (closest in the picture), then I assume the alternator will pivot on that if you release the smaller bolt on the other side of the alternator - just visible with a piece of metal that has a slot in it. That looks to be how you adjust the tension of the belt.